# How to combine sum() where between and group by statement in eloquent orm?

Tags: php, eloquent

I want to produce record who retrieve data sales  in specified date range with 2 parameter input `$date_from` and `$date_to`
so I am trying to combine some SQL function to do that:

```
public function print_report(Request $request) {
    $from = "2018-04-03";
    $to = "2018-04-17";
    $data = AppSalesDetail::select('app_sales_detail.*','app_sales.*')
        ->leftJoin('app_sales','app_sales.app_sales_id','=','app_sales_detail.app_sales_id')    
        ->whereBetween('sale_date', array($from, $to))
        ->groupBy("app_sales_detail.app_sales_id")  
        ->sum('app_sales_detail.sub_total')
        ->get();
}
```

Before I add `->sum('app_sales_detail.sub_total')` inside the query everything works fine as my expect but happen this error after I insert that function

```
Call to a member function groupBy() on string
```

please give me advice to solve that.

Comment: You want one sum per `app_sales_id`, right?

Comment: yes I do. Do have you any advice?
@Jonas Staudenmeir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum()` method only returns one row, you have to add it to `select()`.
You also can't select all the columns:

```
$data = AppSalesDetail::select('app_sales_detail.app_sales_id')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(sub_total) sub_total')
    ->leftJoin('app_sales','app_sales.app_sales_id','=','app_sales_detail.app_sales_id')    
    ->whereBetween('sale_date', array($from, $to))
    ->groupBy("app_sales_detail.app_sales_id")  
    ->get();
```

Comment: it's work. thank you very much @Jonas Staudenmeir.
but can you explain me more? I think when us make agregate function.based on your answer. it's mean we need to ->selectRaw() command?

Comment: If you only want one total sum, you can use the `sum()` method (without `get()`): `AppSalesDetail::where(...)->sum('sub_total')`

Comment: when not using ->selectRaw() It's seems . just used when I need to returning single data not array.

Comment: Yes, that's the difference.